# Django when to use teardown method

Tags: django

According to the docs:

> A TestCase, on the other hand, does not truncate tables and reload
>   initial data at the beginning of a test. Instead, it encloses the test
>   code in a database transaction that is rolled back at the end of the
>   test. It also prevents the code under test from issuing any commit or
>   rollback operations on the database, to ensure that the rollback at
>   the end of the test restores the database to its initial state. In
>   order to guarantee that all TestCase code starts with a clean
>   database, the Django test runner runs all TestCase tests first, before
>   any other tests (e.g. doctests) that may alter the database without
>   restoring it to its original state.

So if I have a test that looks like this:

```
class GeneralUserCreateTest(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        create_roletypes()
        create_permissiontypes()
        self.client = Client()
        self.event = create_event()

    def test_create(self):
        create_url = reverse('event_user_signup', args=[self.event.slug])

        post_data = {
            'signup-account-email': 'foo@bar.com',
            'signup-account-password': 'foobar',
            'signup-account-password2': 'foobar',
            'signup-account-first_name': 'Foo',
            'signup-account-last_name': 'Bar',
        }
        response = self.client.post(create_url, data=post_data)
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 302)

        # check creation of user object
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.filter(email=post_data['signup-account-email']).count(), 1)
        user = User.objects.get(username=post_data['signup-account-email'])

        # user and profile objects created
        self.assertEqual(User.objects.all().count(), 1)
        self.assertEqual(Profile.objects.all().count(), 1)

        # get the first user and profile object to test against submitted field
        user = User.objects.all()[0]
        profile = Profile.objects.all()[0]
        role = Role.objects.filter(event=self.event, profiles=profile)[0]
        self.assertEqual(role.roletype.name, 'General')
        self.assertEqual(user.username, post_data['signup-account-email'])
        self.assertEqual(user.email, post_data['signup-account-email'])
        self.assertEqual(profile.first_name, post_data['signup-account-first_name'])
        self.assertEqual(profile.last_name, post_data['signup-account-last_name'])
```

Is it still necessary to run a `teardown` method or does the `TestCase` class take care of it? If so, when should one use the `teardown` method given the availability of the `TestCase` class?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For the purposes of the database, `tearDown` is pretty pointless, because each test is run in a transaction. However, not everything in a test involves the database. You might test file creation/reading, spin off processes, open network connections, etc. These types of things usually require you to "close" them after you're done. This is what `tearDown` is for, i.e. cleaning up stuff from your `setUp` method, not related to the database. (Though, if you were actually directly connecting to a database, i.e. as the actual Django tests must do to make sure all the DBAPI stuff works properly, you'd need to do clean up there too.)

Answer (score 17):

I was working on a project that handled some file uploads, and i needed to delete the files that were created by the test and the `tearDown` method was very useful in that situation.

```
import shutil

#....
#....

    def tearDown(self):
        shutil.rmtree(settings.UPLOAD_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are using an alternative database like MongoDB or Redis and you need to load in a set of initial data (a "collection"), you will need to override the `tearDown` method too.

See http://www.belchak.com/2011/02/07/unit-testing-django-with-a-nosql-backend/

In general, `django.test.TestCase` does a full database flush at the start of each
new test. This means that we do not need to manually delete objects in our tearDown as Chris Pratt has mentioned above. The next test setUp will make sure the database is clean.

However, if we are using doctests and `unittest.TestCase`, there will be no database flush before tests are run again. At the start of a test, the database will be in whatever state the previous
test left. This means that any stray data left by a previous run would cause conflict.  So if we are using doctests or unittest.TestCase for our django tests, a cleanup might be good practice.

Finally, in more complicated scenarios, it might also make sense to deliberately persist the test database to hunt down specific unit test bugs.

Comment: I've found that `TestCase` does not always flush the db... i'm not sure what causes this, but there are several times I've had to use `TransactionTestCase` to reset the database between tests.

Comment: I don't think I agree with your last point about hunting down unit test bugs. By principle, unit tests are meant to be independent so everything should be contained within a unit test, right? Execution of a test before or after should not affect the run of the current unit test. Could you please explain an example complicated scenario where might need to persist data between tests?

Comment: @Calvin Cheng  If i use unittest.TestCase as oppposed to django.test.TestCase (precisely for the purpose of not having to flush the db after ever single test), then - do you have any advise on using self.assertTemplateUsed(response, 'example.html') method. I get error TestViews' object has no attribute 'assertTemplateUsed'. (but if i use django.test.TestCase  - there's no error. .. but then the database flushes every time.) Any suggestions?