# FactoryBoy: how to teardown?

Tags: django, unit-testing, factory-boy

I don't understand how `teardown` in FactoryBoy + Django works.

I have a testcase like this:

```
class TestOptOutCountTestCase(TestCase):
    multi_db = True

    def setUp(self):
        TestCase.setUp(self)
        self.date = datetime.datetime.strptime('05Nov2014', '%d%b%Y')
        OptoutFactory.create(p_id=1, cdate=self.date, email='inv1@test.de', optin=1)

    def test_optouts2(self):
        report = ReportOptOutsView()
        result = report.get_optouts()
        self.assertEqual(len(result), 1)
        self.assertEqual(result[0][5], -1)
```

`setUp` is running once for all tests correct? Now if I had a second test and needed a clean state before running it, how do I achieve this? Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you don't need `tearDown` in this case, as resetting the database between each test is the [default behaviour](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.TransactionTestCase.fixtures) for a `TestCase`.

See:

> At the start of each test case, before setUp() is run, Django will flush the database, returning the database to the state it was in directly after migrate was called.

...

> This flush/load procedure is repeated for each test in the test case, so you can be certain that the outcome of a test will not be affected by another test, or by the order of test execution.

Or do you mean to limit the creation of instances via the `OutputFactory` to certain tests?

Then you probably shouldn’t put the creation of instances into `setUp`.

Or you create two variants of your TestCase, one for all tests that rely on the factory and one for the ones that don't.

---

Regarding the uses of `tearDown` check this answer: [Django when to use teardown method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9459030/django-when-to-use-teardown-method)